# Trying to understand Keybase's key model and replacing PGP with device keys

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am exploring Keybase and I thought it was merely a wrapper for gpg and connecting its public key with social accounts (e.g. github, twitter, etc...). But after reading the very short and unclear post in https://keybase.io/blog/keybase-new-key-model it seems that Keybase now by default generates 2 key pairs (one is curve25519 for encryption and the other is probably ed25519 for signatures) for each installation/device per user and use these 2 key pairs by default for `keybase sign` and `keybase encrypt` commands.

My question is more about the curve25519 key pair part. Is this design secure since, I think, they have to basically use static-static diffie-hellman for every encryption between any 2 users with same devices or key pairs? I mean if one of the 2 users has his private key compromised this means that every encryption between the 2, whether that user was the sender or receiver is compromised. That imposes a risk on the other user even if he is keeping his private key secure. Am I missing something here?

Woudln't it be better to generate an ephemeral curve25519 key signed by the static ed25519 or whatever the signing key alg is and do ephemeral-static DH? I know it still won't give forward secrecy but at least if the the compromised party is the sender the attacker won't be able to read these messages since he doesn't own the other party' static private key.

Comment: Note that I'm not famiar with keybase or their new key model, and I presume this is the case for a lot of our users. So questions about it may not be answered for some time because of that.